# Sencha Touch CMD installation issues

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-cmd

I have a MAMP server running on the Mac.

in the directory path: **/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/MyApp/sencha-touch-2.2.0-gpl/** my SDK is copied.

I downloaded the latest Sencha CMD tool from the sencha touch website: http://www.sencha.com/products/sencha-cmd/download for Mac version 3.1.1 for Mac

On installing the Sencha CMD tools: I chose Administrator/bin/ folder to install it into. It got installed successfully.

After that, I opened the Terminal window of the Mac, navigated to the SDK folder and typed the **sencha** command. I got the following issues:

[image: The current working directory (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/MyApp/sencha-touch-2.2.0-gpl) is not a recognized Sencha SDK or application folder. Running in backwards compatible mode.]

The Sencha CMD is not reflecting the correct version.

Also, the same warning error pops up when I try to create a new Sencha App.

[image: Error while creating a new project]

Could anyone please guide the correct method of installing Sencha CMD or is there any thing I have missed out?

Thanks,
Ankit Tanna.

Comment: If you tap the command 'which sencha' in a terminal it should give should the path to the Sencha CMD it's using. It's probably still using an old version. You should add remove the old version from your PATH and add the new one.

Comment: How to do the addition and removal of the Old CMD Path. Sorry, I am new to Sencha + Mac. Sencha + Windows is quite easy.

Comment: I got this: 
administrators-MacBook-Pro:~ administrator$ which sencha
/Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-beta3/sencha

Answer (score 0):

For me it's all in `~/.bash_profile`.

Open it with a text editor. Then you should remove the path to the SDK tools and add the path to the Sencha CMD if it's not there yet.

For example, in my `~/.bash_profile`, I have

```
# export PATH=/Users/titouanvanbelle/bin/Sencha/Cmd/3.0.2.288:$PATH
export PATH=/Users/titouanvanbelle/bin/Sencha/Cmd/3.1.1.274:$PATH
```

I commented the path to an older version instead of removing it in case I need it again.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with the bash

I do that you said but the only way that I can activate sencha is create an alias

```
sencha=/Users/AppDev/bin/Sencha/Cmd/3.1.2.342/sencha
```